# Ĉu ekzistas Esperanta ĵurnalo kies artikoloj estas tradukaĵoj de diversaj landaj ĵurnaloj?

Tags: culture

Mi nur havas kiel ekzemplon [*Courrier International*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courrier_International), kiu estas Franca ĵurnalo, kies enhavo ĉefe estas fremdaj artikoloj tradukitaj. Ĉu simila ĵurnalo uzante la saman koncepton ekzistas en Esperantujo?

Comment: Ne respondo, sed rilata afero: FAKA LITERATURO EN ESPERANTO: http://www.eventoj.hu/steb/

Answer (score 4):

Ekzistas la Esperanta versio de Le Monde Diplomatique: https://eo.mondediplo.com

Answer (score 3):

Ankaŭ menciindas la retgazeto Global Voices, kiu ekzistas Esperante kaj en pluraj aliaj lingvoj: https://eo.globalvoices.org

Answer (score 1):

Artikolojn tradukitajn el diversaj lingvoj enhavas Unesko-Kuriero
https://unesdoc.unesco.org/ark:/48223/pf0000374071

Answer (score 0):

Jen:

Ekonomia Bulteno pri Usono

https://ekonomiabultenopriusono.com/